# Software with a blog, CMS and a forum all-in-one?

Tags: php

Requirements:

- PHP (5+ Preferably)
- MySQL (5+ Preferably)
- Apache (2+ Preferably)

Answer (score 1):

You're not defining what you mean by "CMS" vs blog, but we'll gloss over that for the moment.

Expression Engine will handle the blog/general CMS aspects as part of core, and has a forum module.

WordPress will do blogging for you, with some plugins(eg. Pods) that will do what some people would call more "CMS-like" functionality. bbPress could be integrated with it at least as far as 2.9, and I think the current roadmap for it is to become something like a plugin you bolt onto core WordPress; you'll have to look into that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress, phpbb3, and anything else you might want to stack on top of that. These solutions don't really come in a one stop all formate.

Answer (score 0):

[Drupal](http://www.drupal.org) will do that, but it might be overly complicated for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal is the best all-in-on solution hands down. That said, I'd personally go with simpler tools that are good at a single task, e.g. [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/) for a blog (and/or CMS), [Vanilla](http://vanillaforums.org/) for forums.

Comment: Using a number of tools (WordPress for a blog) and Vanilla for forums could hurt your on-site SEO efforts.

Comment: @Melanie Web sites should be made for people, not robots. Plain text documents may be great for SEO but are not very user friendly. This will affect your site's popularity and eventually it's ranking.